# Typescript make return of another type generic

Tags: typescript

I'm using `react` `useReducer` and have a problem with generic types.

I want to have a generic `dispatch`, but typescript makes my `dispatch` not generic.

Here is my [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMBK6AmyDG6UcAvnAGZQQhwDkU6AhvjLQNwCwAUN8AHYwi5ZujgBlGI0GJucOKkmCAjAC55MKPwDmnLnIVT0AJjV9kIAEZFdJbtxgBPMKICCLYBD4AeACpx0AB6CfDiocADW6A4Q5OKK6AB8cAC8Mnpwjs5qPrpyYIwOADYQjDhqEoYA2j4Auja6dlzkyHzunnAMeIRQvv5B6CFhkdGxFYIJABSy6obl8QA008wwHnxqbiuevgncAJRzhmlyDDDIUHyIcAB0NwaC83CVy6tXmeg1as%20eV-lFJTikGyNbj4TwKR53dAPHDAVD5GD4AAWNRSKAw2C6RAmnQIRAeCGm%20niqjgACJSYt0kTDCY4EpKSRdg0uAB6FnyREQZCFAH4RhoUREKjEKx8gUzQRGOCwuB8CDwBSaPhabgwuFSJETBBvFSkyFGClwX7FUpqcmMoA)

```js
function reducer<T extends keyof State>(
  state: State,
  action: Action<T>
): State {
  return { ...state, [action.type]: action.payload };
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    state1: "",
    state2: 1,
});
```

The problem is the type of `dispatch`, its `Dispatch<Action<keyof State>>` instead of `Dispatch<Action<T>>`

Why the return of `useReducer` is not generic? it's use `infer` to extract type from `reducer` parameters but it's not extracting it as generic.

And how to makes `dispatch` generic?

Comment: Instead of generics, I'd suggest you use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wRXALm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz that's actually looking assume, I forgot union, and I think that is an answer thanks

Comment: I don't know what "looking assume" means, but the rest of your comment sounds positive, so I think I will write up an answer here when I get a chance.

Comment: @jcalz typo, i mean awesome

Comment: @jcalz The only issue now I have it is if I have optional field in `Action` can you look at this please https://tsplay.dev/NVbOqN

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mq3yZw) maybe?

Comment: @jcalz thats work tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript can't easily synthesize the sort of higher-order generic types you would need for `useReducer`'s output to continue to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  The compiler gives up and replaces the generic type parameter `T` with its constraint `keyof State`, and thus you're dealing with `Action<keyof State>`, a single object type whose `type` and `payload` properties are no longer separated properly.

Luckily, given this example, you don't have to try to get `dispatch` to be generic, because you can avoid making `reducer` and `Action` generic.  Instead, you can make `Action` a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of your original `Action<T>` type for every `T` in `keyof State`.  Like this:

```
type Action = { [T in keyof State]-?: {
  type: T;
  payload: State[T];
} }[keyof State];

// evaluates to the union:
/* type Action = {
    type: "state1";
    payload: string;
} | {
    type: "state2";
    payload: number;
} */
```

That technique, where you make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it to get a union, is known as making a "distributive object type", as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

And now `reducer()` doesn't need to be generic because its `action` parameter is not generic:

```
function reducer(
  state: State,
  action: Action
): State {
  return { ...state, [action.type]: action.payload };
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
  state1: "",
  state2: 1,
});
```

And now `dispatch()` is a `Dispatch<Action>`, meaning it only accepts `Action` arguments, which can no longer accept mixed `type` and `payload` properties:

```
dispatch({ type: "state2", payload: 123 }); // okay
dispatch({ type: "state2", payload: "" }) //error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMBK6AmyDG6UcAvnAGZQQhwDkU6AhvjLQNwCwAUN8AHYwi5ZujgBlGI0GJucOKkmCAjAC55MKPwDmnLnIVT0AJjV9kIAEZFdJbtxgBPMKICCLYBD5wAvIjgBtABU4fjgAa3QHCHJxRXQAXQBaAH41BFk4R2c1QN05MEYHABsIRhw1CUMg+JtSfwiomMrBGu4Aeja4dAA3RiLkQ1RMiEyAC1FkPg8+FXaAKkynV3dPHxk9OUXsuAAiA2UdvM2C4tLy9U0+HW4yAB91za30NT24o0OM-MKSstNzKygtTmbTsXHIkxWXgYeEIUAAFBl9s9YoYADQZZgwaZqNxYzzcACUFTiDzgDBgyCgXiQADo6UjUQFMdMaVkEmpmZ4aScfjhSDZQfhPAoAgy4DhgKgCjB8KN4ms0FhcAQiHDoSqoIz0hskapdjt0Tq3molIaSATdB04EK+CKJVKpLK1AARSXS2UAHlx0wAfKD7e7RnCkGyXkj3oyeWcTUYAMykC1wK0QMKFbgBx1BkNLMNvA1wKO-fUJpNtIhUKBAA)